# Sklearn decision tree plot does not appear

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to follow scikit learn example on decision trees:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, y)
```

When I try to plot the tree:

```
tree.plot_tree(clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target))
```

I get

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-e72b33a93ee6> in <module>
----> 1 tree.plot_tree(clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target))

NameError: name 'iris' is not defined
```

Comment: Why would the name `iris` be defined?  It has never been defined like `iris = ...` or imported

Comment: Is that all your code? The error tells you `iris` isn't defined - and it isn't from what you've shared.

Comment: Where are you writing your code? Even if for some reason you couldn’t deduce the problem from the error message, your IDE should point it out, no?

Comment: My "problem" is now solved but I am writing this code using IPython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iris` doesn't exist if you don't *assign* it. Use this line to plot:

```
tree.plot_tree(clf.fit(X, y))
```

You already assigned the `X` and `y` of `load_iris()` to a variable so you can use them.

Additionally, make sure the `graphviz` library's `bin` folder is in `PATH`.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have tried this before but I got no figure. Maybe because I am using `Ipython`.

Comment: I'm also using ipython. What happens when you run it?

Comment: There is no figure. Only a (digraph (?) file) like ```[Text(248.0, 338.79999999999995, 'X[2] <= 2.45\ngini = 0.667\nsamples = 150\nvalue = [50, 50, 50]'),```...

Comment: Sklearn uses `graphviz`. Do you have it installed, and its `bin` filepath added to PATH?

Comment: Yes, I have installed it using `conda` (`python-graphviz`).

Comment: That's not enough. You need to add it to path as I said

Answer (score 3):

Your problem was different, but I ended up here through googling this issue and you have also same-ish issue present.

At least on windows matplotlib (which is used to show the tree with `tree.plot_tree`) will not show anything if you don't have `plt.show()` somewhere.

```
from sklearn import tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sometree = ....

tree.plot_tree(sometree)

plt.show() # mandatory on Windows
```